# AJAX and HTML: how server can control client web page?

Tags: html, ajax

I know use AJAX to periodically poll server for the command can achieve this, but what if the server want to change a property of web page element.

Besides polling, is there any async event that client web page AJAX can listen on?

Comment: your question does not really make sense !

Comment: Actually it does make sense - its along the lines of: its easy enough for a page to poll the server to pull commands but is there a way for the server to push commands to the client page. @zerkms has provided a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look at [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)